# c++0x_warning.h

Tags: c++

Пишу простую программу на С++ (учусь) и тут при компиляции в IDE у меня в заголовочном файле (название в заголовке вопроса) появился этот тест об ошибке. Как исправить? Я почитал про лицензию и не понимаю в чем причина. Ошибка появилась сразу после того, как добавил в программу библиотеку
`<random>`

```
// Copyright (C) 2007-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
//
// This file is part of the GNU ISO C++ Library.  This library is free
// software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
// terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
// Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
// any later version.

// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.

// Under Section 7 of GPL version 3, you are granted additional
// permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version
// 3.1, as published by the Free Software Foundation.

// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License and
// a copy of the GCC Runtime Library Exception along with this program;
// see the files COPYING3 and COPYING.RUNTIME respectively.  If not, see
// <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/** @file bits/c++0x_warning.h
 *  This is an internal header file, included by other library headers.
 *  Do not attempt to use it directly. @headername{iosfwd}
 */

#ifndef _CXX0X_WARNING_H
#define _CXX0X_WARNING_H 1

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: И что конкретно непонятно из текста предупреждения? "Этот файл требует поддержки компилятором и библиотекой 
стандарта ISO C ++ 2011. Эта поддержка является экспериментальной и должна быть включен с помощью ключей `-std=c++11` или `-std=gnu++11` компилятора"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как сделать чтобы у меня code::blockes поддерживал С++11?

Code::Blocks сам  по себе ничего не поддерживает, поддержка нужна со стороны компилятора. Настраивается она, очевидно, там же, где и другие опции компилятора, в английской версии это `Settings->Compiler...`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вон же четко виден флажок `Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]`. Его и надо отметить...

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает)

Answer (score 0):

Вам четко написали - ваш компилятор по умолчанию **не поддерживает** C++11, так что вы должны при компиляции таких вещей указать дополнительный ключик - `-std=c++11` или `-std=gnu++11`...

Comment: Я использую code::blocks для разработки. Вы случайно не в курсе, как сделать чтобы у меня code::blockes поддерживал С++11?

Comment: Откровенно говоря, нет. Но в любой среде в настройках проекта где-то такой пунктик имеется - настройка параметров компиляции. Либо прямо позволит указать ключ, либо будет что-то типа опции использовать стандарт c++11...